# Feature layers don't appear in print result?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, printing, query-task

I have a problem when I print my map, when I display the result I find only one feauture of twenty. the result does't contain all features. I used esri/dijit/PrintTask

```
verifier: function(){ //verifier() is an onClick event of a button
var url= 'the way/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/PrintingTools/GPServer/Export%20Web%20Map%20Task';
var printTask=new PrintTask(url);
var params = new PrintParameters();
params.map =this.map;
printTask.execute(params,this.printResult);
},printResult: function(event)
{
console.log(event);
window.open(event.url, "_blank")
}
```

feature layers which don't appears on the result of print, are those where there URLs aren't links of map service, but a link to java servlets that they connect to the map service(one servlet for each map service).

maybe the print task desn't make the redirection, it seach the serviceMAP from the url in the definition of the feature layer and as it's the link of the servlet.

Sorry for my English because I'm more French than English.